# Matrix powers of product of diagonalizable and orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Suppose I have the following matrix constructed from some orthogonal matrix $O$ and a $\pm 1$ diagonal matrix $D=diag(\pm1,\dots,\pm1)$
$$
A = O D O^{-1} D.
$$
Is there a simple way to evaluate $A^n$ for positive integer $n$ in a similar way to e.g. a diagonalizable matrix $B$?
$$
B^n = (P L P^{-1})^n = P L^n P^{-1} .
$$
I feel this ought to be the case given how $A$ is decomposed into a product of orthogonal and diagonal matrices but alas it is not clear to me if this is always so. Of course $A$ is also an orthogonal matrix and can itself be diagonalized
$$
A = O D O^{-1} D = RTR^{-1}
$$
but do $R,T$ have clear expressions in terms of $O,D$?

EDIT:
Some further work on my end indicates that the same question when
$$
A = D^{1/2} O D O^{-1} D^{1/2},
$$
is also acceptable. Answers in this direction would be helpful, though the original question is still my primary goal.

Comment: If $D$ is still the diagonal reflection matrix, does not $A=\left(D^{1/2}OD^{-1/2}\right)D^{2}\left(D^{-1/2}O^{-1}D^{1/2}\right)$ give you the diagonalisation of $A$?

Comment: I don't believe so. $D^{1/2}$ is complex if $D$ is anything other than the identity so the inverse of $D^{1/2} O D^{-1/2}$ is not $D^{-1/2} O^{-1} D^{1/2}$ but rather $D^{1/2} O^{-1} D^{-1/2}$. So while the above is equal to $A$, it is not the diagonalisation in the form $A=PTP^{-1}$, for orthogonal matrix $P$ and diagonal matrix $T$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: When you say $\pm 1$ diagonal matrix $D$, do you mean $D = \pm diag(1,...,1)$?

Comment: @KevinS $D=\mathrm{diag}(\pm 1,\dots,\pm 1)$. Otherwise my comment above would be valid after factoring out the $-1$ scalar. (Also the problem would be trivial, to start with)

Comment: Yes, @paperskilltrees is correct.

Comment: @User71942 Any update?

Comment: @paperskilltrees In a sense, I believe this question needs to be extremely hard to compute, as an efficient answer would yield an efficient way of performing something like Grover's search efficiently (of quantum information fame), which would have shocking ramifications for computer science and complexity theory as a whole. So alas, I think the sort of answer I was hoping for does not exist.